# When downloading a zip file in classic asp, I am getting 'file is being used by another process error'

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, download, asp-classic

I am working on classic asp with vbscript application.

**Requirement:**
Consolidate files in a server folder to a zip file and download it. This should happen in a single button click.

**What I have achieved:**
I have a button called 'Consolidate Files' that when clicked opens a window pop up with 'Download' and 'Close' button. When clicking on 'Download' button a prompt to save the file is shown and user can open, save or save as the file.

**Code I used:**

x.asp

```
<input type="button" value="Consolidate Files" id='btn_consolidated' >
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn_consolidated').click(function(){window.open('y.asp?id=<%=id%>&dothis=Consolidate',"DownloadWindow", "width=500,height=300")});
</script>
```

y.asp

```
dothis = Request("dothis")

Select Case dothis

    Case "Consolidate"
    id = Request("id")
        Dim userId, Code 
        Dim filename1,location1,query,rs1,Zip
        userId = Session("UserId")
        Dim fs, f
        set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        set zip = new aspZip 

        'location1 = "..\doc\Files\["+userId+"]-"+id
        location1 = dirdefault+"TempUserFiles\"
        if not fs.FolderExists(location1) then
            fs.CreateFolder(location1)
        end if

        query="select Filename,Location, Code from files f where id=" + id + " "
        Set rs1 = conn.Execute(query)

        Code = rs1("Code")
        location1 = location1 + "["+userId+"]-"+rs1("Code")

        'on error resume next

        if fs.FolderExists(location1) then
            fs.DeleteFolder(location1)
        end if
        fs.CreateFolder(location1)    

        'If Err.Number <> 0 Then    
        '    Response.Write(location1)
        'return
        'End if

    'All files in dirdefault + rs1("location") path is added to a zip file
        zip.OpenArquieve(location1+"\"+Code +".zip")    
        do while not rs1.Eof
            f = fs.GetFile(dirdefault + rs1("location"))
            zip.Add(f)
            rs1.MoveNext
            'f.close
        Loop 

        zip.CloseArquieve()
        rs1.close
        set zip = nothing

        set fs = nothing   
        set f = nothing
        Session("fileLocation") = location1+"\"+Code +".zip"
        Response.redirect "Download.asp?id="+id

    Case "Download"

        Dim userFolder

        location1 = Session("fileLocation")
        set zip = nothing
        set fs = nothing   
        set f = nothing

        Set objUpload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
        if objUpload.FileExists(location1) then
            objUpload.SendBinary location1', true, "application/octet-stream", true ' this is line 483 where error is throwing
           'response.write "file exists"    
        else
            Response.redirect "fileNotFound.asp?id=" + idFile
        end if
        set objUpload.ActiveConnection = Nothing
        set objUpload = nothing
```

Download.asp

```
id = Request("id")
Dim userId, Code, objUpload
Dim filename1,userFolder, location1,query,rs1,Zip
userId = Session("UserId")
Dim fs, f


query="select top 1 Code from MainTable er where er.id = " + id 
Set rs1 = conn.Execute(query)
Code= rs1("Code")
%>
<html>
    <head><title>Download document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css" title="dcsStyle">        
        <script language="JavaScript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#btn_back').click(function () { self.close() });
                $('#btn_Download').click(function () { location = 'y.asp?id=<%=id%>&dothis=Download'; });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Consolidated files download for <%=Code%></h1>
    <br />
        <input type ="button" id="btn_Download" value="Download" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' id='btn_back' value='Close' />
```

**Working:**
x.asp is my main page where I have the button 'Consolidate Files'. When this button is clicked, the consolidation of files to a single zip file happens in y.asp under case "Consolidate". Here a new folder is created for each unique 'Code' number and all files taken from a server location is added into a zip file and saved in the new folder that was created.

When the user clicks on 'Download' button in the popup window, the case 'Download'  in  y.asp works where the zip file that was created in the previous step is available to the user to save to their local drive.

**Problem:**
in y.asp under case "Download", I am getting the following error at

> objUpload.SendBinary location1', true, "application/octet-stream",  true
>   The error is inconsistent and does not occur all the time. Sometimes, no matter what I do, the error persists even after multiple trials to download the file. Also, the case "Condolidate" functionality always works smoothly and a fresh file is created each time. Any help would be appreciated.

**Error:**

> Technical Information (for support personnel) •Error Type: 
>   Persits.Upload.1 (0x800A001A) The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another process.  /myapp/pr/y.asp, line
>   483

Comment: Try to disable your antivirus.

Comment: Which line is line 483?

Comment: I have edited the post and commented line that shows error. It is in y.asp under case "Download"

Comment: I had tried by hard coding first and it was working perfectly. But this is the code that I need to use and it is not working as expected. Also there are other pages in application that downloads the file without any issue. I had used the very same code here too.